# CORS Issue when using Three.js TextureLoader

Tags: reactjs, three.js

[image]

There is no problem simply importing and outputting an image without using TextureLoader for the same image URL.

As soon as I use TextureLoader I get a CORS error.

The sources of my FrontEnd Server and BackEnd Server are different, but I think there is no problem with the CORS setting when it is inferred that image output is possible.

I tried several workarounds, but all failed.

1. ?not-from-cache-please
2. new THREE.TextureLoader(); textureLoader.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";

Is there any other way?

Is there any other way than to make the source of the image and the server to be queried the same?